# How to use a string as df$column call (R)

Tags: r

Lets say I have a large program where we call a certain variable many times in the code.  This variable will change for different analysis.  At the beginning of the code I want to create a call where I only change the variable once.  How can I use this to call a df column?

example

```
df <- stuff

traitofinterest <- color
```

later on in the code... how do I use this to call stuff$color?

`stuff$traitofinterest`    no workey

edit:  Yes, that works!  I am not sure why I overlooked this basic usage..  Im still relatively new to R.

Comment: You mean like `stuff[, traitofinterest]` or some variant of that?

Comment: You might want to start with an overview of subsetting: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

Answer (score 4):

The "yes workey" solution would be to use something like:

```
stuff[, traitofinterest]
```

or

```
stuff[, traitofinterest, drop = FALSE]
```

depending on the desired output structure you want when there is only one variable in "traitofinterest" (which it sounds like there will be in general).